# Sync related data using angularfire/collection

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I want to use angularfirecollection to keep one-way sync with a list of data. The structure is a list of 'things' with various properties (e.g. 'Likes') and users who each hold a subset of 'things' keys (e.g. -jsdzsdrestofkey: true). U

sing angularfirecollection (or firebase native 'on'), I can sync up all things that a particular user has... I can also grab (using firebase native 'once') each 'thing''s properties to display.

In angular, however, I need to use $apply() to inject the property data into scope for each item in the user's 'thing' list. To keep things in sync, I suppose I can use firebase's on change event... But this all requires me to create new references for each thing in a user's list.

What is the best way to approach grabbing relational data in firebase, while keeping both the list and the relational data in sync?

Thanks!
Irfaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you should use [FirebaseIndex](https://github.com/Zenovations/FirebaseIndex) and feed the index directly into an `angularFireCollection`. Then you wouldn't need to use `$apply` since the `thing` data will already be in the `$scope`, and everything will stay synced:

```
var index = new FirebaseIndex(fb.child('users/789/thing_list'), fb.child('things'));
$scope.things = angularFireCollection(index);
// $scope.things will contain the user's things with the associated thing data
```

Comment: Thank you! I had run into Firebaseindex in my search before posting but forgot to mention it in my question above. Is this the only solution out there? Is there nothing native to firebase or angularfire?

Comment: For this exact use case I think this is as "native" as it gets; if I'm not mistaken FirebaseIndex is maintained by the Firebase team.

Comment: For future reference, the Firebase team is now developing an official library for joins/etc. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util